# What files can be downloaded from a website root directory?

Tags: asp.net, web

If i have a page on my website called blah.aspx then there will be another file there called
blah.aspx.vb

I can browse to blah.aspx but if I try to browse to blah.aspx.vb, I'll get 'file not found' page.

If I change the name of blah.aspx.vb to blah.zip it can be downloaded via the browser.

If I change the name to blah.qaz I'll get the 'file not found' again.

I suspect that the server will not allow the .aspx.vb file to be downloaded but if it doesn't protect a .zip file why does it protect a made up .qaz or is that just a shortcoming of the browser?

Are there file extensions that a server will actively protect?

Are there file extensions it deliberately won't hide (e.g zip)?

What are the rules and where can you find them?

Comment: Do you know what webserver you're using?

Comment: @MichaelJCox  IIS8 I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS 7 maps 'allowed' extensions (or extensions that it will handle) in the [applicationhost.config](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/introduction-to-applicationhostconfig) file.

If you really want to allow a 'qaz' extension, you could add a mimeMap to add it as static content. Don't know what webserver you're using, but if you're on II7+, you [should be able to add it to your web.config](http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2008/03/25/how-to-add-mime-types-with-iis7-web-config.aspx):

```
<configuration>

  <system.webServer>

    <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".qaz" mimeType="text/plain" />
    </staticContent>

  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

If you're on an earlier version of IIS, [then it's a different ballgame.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524661%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) If you're on some other webserver, you'll have to search around for the configuration information, but most will have some configuration file that states which extensions they are ok serving.

Comment: Thanks this is just what I wanted. This sort of knowledge, is it books on windows server I'd need to read to get it?